# spring-boot-starter-cache with camunda shows java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority class not found

Tags: log4j, camunda, spring-boot-starter

I'm using camunda (a business process flow tool, not sure if that has anything to do with it).  pom.xml is below (only removed header & maven build plugin).

When I build & deploy in Tomcat I get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priorityorg/apache/log4j/Priority".  Stack trace is below.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <camunda-bom.version>7.6.0</camunda-bom.version>
    <mssql-jdbc.version>6.2.0.jre8</mssql-jdbc.version>
    <resteasy-spring-boot-starter.version>2.3.2-RELEASE</resteasy-spring-boot-starter.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${camunda-bom.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Camunda Engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-engine-spring</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-engine-rest</artifactId>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Starters -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MS-SqlServer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${mssql-jdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- RestEasy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy-spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Ehcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.10.4</version> -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Stack trace is below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'freeMarkerConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/freemarker/FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration$FreeMarkerWebConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority
        at freemarker.log._Log4JLoggerFactory.getLogger(_Log4JLoggerFactory.java:67)
        at freemarker.log.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:284)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory.<clinit>(TaglibFactory.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer.setServletContext(FreeMarkerConfigurer.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ServletContextAwareProcessor.java:103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Priority
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 36 more
```

I'm continuing to work on this...  any clues would help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround & Tomcat starts up cleanly w/o above error.  My searching indicated a potential classLoader problem in spring-boot-starter-cache during the "FreeMarkerAutoConfigurer" bean creation.  I'm not 100% sure about the cause, but the below fix worked for me.

To override the above "FreeMarkerAutoConfigurer" bean creation problem, I added below pom dependency:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Tomcat starts up fine now & I've verified that caching w/ Spring annotations works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `log4j` dependency. Try adding this to your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

OR

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

[Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging)

[Spring-Boot Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html)

Comment: No, already tried that & others like slf4f-over-log4,etc.... did not work.  Please see my below answer - it worked.  But i'm not sure yet what the root cause of the problem was.

Comment: No, spring-boot-starter-logging is already in my spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.  Tried spring-boot-starter-log4j2, & got below exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Work/tomcat-camunda760/server/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/Clinical/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar).`

My below answer worked.  But i'm not sure yet what the root cause of the problem was.